# Some characters in the string cannot be replaced

Tags: php

I am trying to change this string

**Test - GGA ökologie Geschäftsführer.PDF**

into this:

**test_-_gga_oekologie_geschaaeftsfuuehrer.pdf**

This is what I have tried:

```
$characters = array('ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ü', ' ');
$converted_characters = array('ae', 'oe', 'ue', 'AE', 'OE', 'UE', '_');
$string = 'Test - GGA ökologie Geschäftsführer.PDF';

echo strtolower(str_replace($characters, $converted_characters , $string));
```

The code above returns: **test_-_gga_ökologie_geschäftsführer.pdf**

As you see the string still contains the characters **ö** and **ä**.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: try add header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: have you tried double quotes?

Comment: most likely it's an encoding problem. in my test with your code in an utf8-saved php file everything works like a charm.

Comment: Your input-string seems to be garbled. Just type the umlauts with you keyboard and your code should work

Comment: Tested it in 5.5 5.6 7.0 your string is wrongly encoded. when you type it manually it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. I have checked it. You have to copy and replace the characters from your string to array. And it will do the job. The characters in your array and in your string are different.

Answer (score 5):

They are not the same unicode character. If you copy and paste the `ö` character from your string and paste it in the array it works as intended.

Answer (score 5):

With regex

```
$characters = array('/ä/u', '/ö/u', '/ü/u', '/Ä/u', '/Ö/u', '/Ü/u', '/ /' );
$converted_characters = array('ae', 'oe', 'ue', 'AE', 'OE', 'UE', '_');  
$string = 'Test - GGA ökologie Geschäftsführer.PDF';

echo strtolower(preg_replace($characters, $converted_characters , $string));
```